# what is the different methods available in _.invoke() using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My Code:

```
  var arr = [[5,4,3],[3,7,88],[99,66,48]];
  //Sort
  var testInvoke = _.invoke(arr, 'sort');
```

- In the `_.invoke` function function name is `sort`
- So that the all arrange in sorted order and in `testInvoker` data is

  ```
  [[3,4,5],[3,7,88],[48,66,99]]
  ```
- My Question is that  `_.invoke` through which other operation may i perform like `sort`.
- Other than `sort` i am only found `slice`
- If any one know the list of operations or else any other reference contain please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question let's first see what [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) does internally:

```
function (obj, method) {
     var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
     var isFunc = _.isFunction(method);
     return _.map(obj, function(value) {
        return (isFunc ? method : value[method]).apply(value, args);
    });
}
```

From here it's obvious that `method` should be any method, list items might have. For example if `obj` is an Array, then `method` can be any method this array items have. Take an array of strings:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

Every string have bunch of methods which come from String prototype. It means that one can use say `String.prototype.toUpperCase` method in `_.invoke`:

```
_.invoke(["one", "two", "three"], "toUpperCase");
```

and it will produce new array:

```
["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]
```

So the answer to your question: `method` can be any method supported by items of the object being iterated. This can be prototype methods, or own properties of the object:

```
function User(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.getName = function() {return this.name};
}

var user1 = new User('Thomas');
var user2 = new User('Mann');

_.invoke([user1, user2], 'getName'); // => ["Thomas", "Mann"]
```

In case of your question array `[[5,4,3],[3,7,88],[99,66,48]]` besides `sort` you can use any other [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) methods, like, `join`, concat, reduce, etc.

Comment: but sir this getName is User define function but i want to know just inbult like `sort`

Comment: Like I said methods that can be used depends on the type of items in the list. If items are arrays like in your question, then you can use Array prototype methods. Here is the list https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype